# backbone.js this._configure undefined when calling views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

TypeError: Result of expression 'this._configure' [undefined] is not a function.

I keep running into this error any time I extend Backbone.View

my app structure looks like :

//index.js

```
$(function(){ 
  window.Project = Backbone.Model.extend({});
  window.ProjectCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({});
  window.projects = new ProjectCollection;
  window.ProjectView = Backbone.View.extend({});
  window.view = ProjectView({});
  window.view.render();
});
```

Even with this blank structure I still get the error, and when I have all my code filled in I get the exact same error

Am I missing a dependancy? in my index.html I load the following in order:

```
jquery.js
underscore.js
backbone.js
(and at the bottom of my body) index.js
```

And if I take the 'window' off of my variables i get the same error.

No matter how I approach backbone.js I keep getting this same error... how do I fix this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Try

```
window.view = new ProjectView;
```

instead of

```
window.view = ProjectView({});
```

Comment: Good to hear. Please mark this answer correct if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

I was recently seeing this error too `TypeError: this._configure is not a function` and it was because I had:

`var myView = someView();`

instead of:

`var myView = new someView();`

Answer (score 0):

I needed to pass arguments to my view, so none of the options here worked for me.

I had this code:

```
return new app.module('foo').View({id: 1});
```

Changing it to this worked:

```
var view = app.module('foo').View;
return new view({id: 1});
```